# Flexbox column layout wrap with fixed height doesn't stretch the parent inline-block container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm laying out a list of items which are flown top-to-bottom into multiple columns.
Therefore, the flexbox adjusts its width automatically as I add more items.
But the parent inline-block div isn't stretched by this child flexbox.
Seems like a bug in CSS to me.

You can see it yourself in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dnc8h57n/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #e46119;
    border: 1px solid #626262;
    margin: 3px;
    flex: 1;
}

.flexbox {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;

    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;

    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;

    align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;

    height: 400px;
    background-color: #dce7f2;
    border: 1px solid #2a4f73;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why `inline-block` on the container? Come to that, why have a container at all?

Comment: Well, it's the design: a sidebar (container) which has a "position: absolute", and the main column which has a corresponding "margin-right".

Comment: maybe there's a better way laying out the whole thing. I may consult with our designer on that.

Comment: Maybe we could place the sidebar on the top of the main content.
Still, that would look prettier on the right side.

Comment: Also there is `display:inline-flex` if you want it to be inline level.

Comment: Ok, I'm resorting to { width: 400px; overflow: auto; } for the sidebar for now - it seems quite a good web design decision. I'll look into inline flex, thank for the suggestion

Comment: By the way, see this - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247963

Comment: Oh, yeah, this is this same bug.

Comment: For internet searchers, another helpful approach is to put column-count: 2 (or whatever) on the wrapper and display: inline-block on each child.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's really a bug.
See this issue for more info.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247963
(it's the same behaviour both in chrome and firefox).
I guess I'll close it for now, until they fix it.